# Transfer smart pointer ownership to container

Tags: c++, containers, smart-pointers

I have data structures that usually are managed via `std::unique_ptr`, for example the expressions in an AST.

```
struct BinExpr {
 std::unique_ptr<Expr> left;    // Left owns the expression
 std::unique_ptr<Expr> right;   // Right owns the expression
};
```

which works well in most situations.

But sometimes I do not have a fixed amount of expressions to own, for example in a list

```
struct ListExpr {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Expr>> exprs; // Exprs owns pointers which each own an expression 
};
```

But I don't like this additional indirection through the smart-pointer in the vector and I think it does not express the semantic which I want to have. 
Instead of smart pointers owning the expressions, I think that the vector should own the expressions.

But I have the problem that expressions are always created in smart pointers (or at least as raw pointers):

```
std::unique_ptr<Expr> parse_expr() { ... }
```

Is there an elegant way to transfer the ownership from `parse_expr` calls (which have type `std::unique_ptr<Expr>` to a `std::vector<Expr>`? Of cource the `Expr` must not be copied while doing so.
Something like

```
std::vector<Expr> exprs;
exprs.push_back(move_from_ptr_to_vec(parse_expr()));
```

So basically, currently I use them like this

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Expr>> exprs;
exprs.push_back(std::move(parse_expr()));
return std::unique_ptr<ListExpr>(exprs);   // List has a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Expr>>
```

but I want it like that

```
std::vector<Expr> exprs;
exprs.push_back(parse_expr());
return std::unique_ptr<ListExpr>(exprs);   // List has a std::vector<Expr>
```

Comment: Is it correct to assume that `Expr` is a base class, with a virtual destructor and such?

Comment: Are these AST Exprs part of a class hierarchy with virtual methods?

Comment: Do you want to have a `std::vector<Expr> exprs;` instead of `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Expr>> exprs;`?

Comment: `Expr` can be a base class, but it does not have to  be a base class. But it has a destructor which must be called when the owner goes out of scope. And yes, I want a `std::vector<Expr>`

Comment: If your object already created dynamically and owned by a `std::unique_ptr` then the best choice for vector to have `std::unique_ptr` inside. Putting object to vector without copying or moving is not possible.

Comment: Note move is redundant here, do not put it everywhere just in case: `exprs.push_back(std::move(parse_expr()));`

Comment: "But I don't like this additional indirection through the smart-pointer" this is perfectly good example for "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: @Slava Now I see that I actually need the indirection, however this has nothing to   with optimizations. I was more concerned about the design and semantics and don't really care for performance

Comment: If you care about design and semantics then you need to ask first, why object is returned as `std_unique_ptr` by`exprs()`? Changing semantics here is way too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> std::vector<Expr> exprs;
> exprs.push_back(parse_expr());
> ```

Doesn't work, because `parse_expr()` returns a smart pointer. You must indirect through the pointer to get the pointed object:

```
exprs.push_back(*parse_expr());
```

> `Expr` must not be copied while doing so.

Then move, presuming that is OK:

```
exprs.push_back(std::move(*parse_expr()));
```

---

However, consider *why* they expressions are allocated dynamically in the first place. Presumably, they are pointers to polymorphic base sub objects. In such case moving from the base would probably not be useful to you, and the whole concept of array of base objects is probably wrong.

> `Expr` can be a base class

In this case `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Expr>>` is what you need.

Comment: Ok, I see that in my current case (where Expr actually is a base-class) I do need the vector of pointers. Just out of curiosity, do I not need to `release` the smart pointer before the `move`?

Comment: @danielspaniol no, you must not release the smart pointer. If you did, then the memory would leak. Releasing is only done when the ownership of the pointer is transferred (into something other than a unique pointer). Here we don't take ownership of the pointed object, we simply move from that object.

Comment: Don't forget, the move doesn't actually move the dynamically-allocated thing, or do anything to it that changes its lifetime; it merely [potentially] steals the _contents_ of that thing. So your original unique_ptr still has cleaning up to do, it's just cleaning up a dynamically-allocated moved-from ("dead") thing. To `release` would be to tell it not to do that, but then you leak the dead thing. And if you think this is confusing, that's because it is!

Answer (score -4):

Assuming your `Expr` is a polymorphic, or even abstract, base class, in brief: no. `std::vector` is for concrete types, and if you store plain pointers in it you are immediately subject to the rule of n, n > 3. You'll need to manually `delete` `Expr`s, which currently `std::unique_ptr` does for you. And crafting a more automated abstract-type container is hardly worth the effort.

BTW, `std::unique_ptr` does not own anything. One of its primary purposes is to let classes own their members that, for some reason, cannot be immediately kept by-value; being an abstract base is quite a legitimate instance of such a reason. Remember: you own your objects, not your pointer; all it does is relieve you from unnecessary burden of basic management of your objects.

Comment: *"std::unique_ptr does not own anything"* Owning a resource is precisely the goal of a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Yes, and it does not manage lifetime, its destructor and other methods do.

Comment: I don't understand why there needs to be a distinction between what a type does, and what a type's member functions (and destructor and constructors) do. A type's behavior is described by it's member functions. What it's members do *is* what the type does.

Comment: "you own your objects, not your pointer; all it does is relieve you from unnecessary burden of basic management of your objects." being responsible to call delete on a dynamically allocated object is the definition of "owning" the object afaik, what else should it mean to "own" an object ?!?

Comment: from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr): "std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that **owns** and manages another object through a pointer and disposes of that object when the unique_ptr goes out of scope." ... I dont want to exclude the possibility that you have a valid definition of "ownership", though if it differs so substantially from the commonly used one you should explain what it is ;)

Comment: @bipll By that logic, `std::vector` doesn't own its contents either, because that's taken care of by its member functions.